# How to Run Remote Debugger As Server with No Authentication

Tags: visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I managed to get remote debugging working on our Windows Server 2008 R2 Server running some ASP.Net WebSites manually (not as a service)

However, I want to run it as a service and I can't figure out how to set it for no authentication as a service or how to specify what users have access to connect to it.

Does anyone know if it has a manual config file somewhere I can modify in notepad, or something of that nature?